# How to add XmlNamespaces to XmlSerializer Type before Attribute

Tags: c#, xsd, attributes, xmlserializer

I implementing XSD in C#. I have created c# classes from XSD using XSD.EXE.
In XML, there is a schemaVersion attribute that need to be placed as last attribute at root level.
I'm adding namespace to xml while Serialize to StreamWriter, the namespace is serialized after schemaVersion and i want to add this before schemaVersion so that the schemaVersion attribute placed as last attribute at root level.

Target API accepts XML data only when schemaVersion attribute is the last attribute at root level.

Here is class code that generated using XSD.EXE

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.81.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.Test123.com")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.Test123.com", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Request
{
    private decimal schemaVersionField;

    public Request()
    {                
            this.schemaVersionField = ((decimal)(4.0m));
    }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
       public decimal schemaVersion
       {
          get
            {
               return this.schemaVersionField;
            }
         set
           {
             this.schemaVersionField = value;
           }
       }
}
```

Code to Create and send webRequest

```
public class WebRequestPost<T>
    {
        public void Post(T t)
        {
            // Create a request for the URL. 
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://Test123.com/APIRequest");
            request.Method = "POST";        
            request.ContentType = "text/xml";
            var stream = request.GetRequestStream();
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

            var soapWriter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));            

           var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
           ns.Add("req", "http://www.Test123.com");

            soapWriter.Serialize(writer, t);            

            writer.Close();

            // Get the response.
            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {                     
                Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
                {
                    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Output i'm getting:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<req:ShipmentRequest schemaVersion="4.0" xmlns:req="http://www.Test123.com">
</req:ShipmentRequest>
```

Expected output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><req:ShipmentRequest xmlns:req="http://www.Test123.com" schemaVersion="4.0">
</req:ShipmentRequest>
```

Anyone have an idea that how to add specific attribute as last attribute at root level?
Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Sushil

Comment: Is the desired change just cosmetic, or is there a broken parser involved somewhere?

Comment: Attribute order should not matter.

Comment: On further investigation, i found that Target API accepts XML data only when schemaVersion attribute is the last attribute at root level.